# How add data to javascript array php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have form which is supposed to add products to cart:

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['id']?>" id="productId" name="productId">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['fasi2']?>" id="price">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 80px" type="submit" name="add" onclick="myFunction()">დამატება</button>
</form>

<script>
   var products= [];
   function myFunction(){
       products.push("<?php echo $product['id']?>\<?php echo $product['price']?>\");
       alert("<?php echo $product['id']?> added Succesfully")
   }
</script>
```

i need to add max 5 product to cart and then checkout. but this code is not working it refreshes the page and array products is empty each time

Comment: You used the tag `ajax`. You can use that to send js values to php.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this code and also use the ajax to send value in php session.

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['id']?>" id="productId" name="productId">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['fasi2']?>" id="price">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 80px" type="submit" name="add" onclick="myFunction()">დამატება</button>
</form>

<script>
    var products= [];
    var prices = [];
    function myFunction(){
        var product = $('#productId').val();
        var price   = $('#price').val();
        products.push(product);
        prices.push(price);
        alert( product +" added Succesfully ");
    }
</script>
```

if you want to see product array include this line in script function. check in your google chrome console. :)

```
console.log(products);
```

Comment: There is no assurance that OP is using jQuery.

Comment: <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 80px" type="button" name="add" onclick="myFunction()">დამატება</button> just replace your button code html to this.

Comment: it added the value in array but when i click another button it inserts same id in array

Comment: please explain what you say ?

Comment: there are several product on the page displayed with foreach loop. and i inserted the code above. But onclick the array products is filled with first product ID no matter which button you click

Answer (score 1):

Use `ajax`

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['id']?>" id="productId" name="productId">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['fasi2']?>" id="price" name="price">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 80px" type="submit" name="add" id="click_button">დამატება</button>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).click(function(){
 var productId = $('#productId').val();
 var price= $('#price').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: "productId=" + productId+ "&price=" + price,
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
     <!-- code here -->
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The server renders your php code, generating your html, javascript code. 
Then your browser is rendering your frontend code ( html and javascript ).
You can do this in your frontend:

```
 <form method="post" >
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['id']?>" id="productId" name="productId">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product['fasi2']?>" id="price">
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary"     style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 80px" type="submit" name="add" onclick="showProducts()">Press me</button>
 </form>

<script>
 var products= new Array(),prices = new Array();
 function showProducts()
{
    let product = $('#productId').val();
    let price = $('#price').val();
    products.push(product);
    prices.push(price);
    alert(products);
    alert(prices);
 }
</script>
```